# Add rows with select option in Javascript with Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, rows

I need to create a dynamic field in javascript with text and select input option.

I run the code in JSFiddle and everything goes without problems, but when I run on my server, the select option disappear [like this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjXfu.png).

This is the code:

**HTML**

```
<table id="Campos">
    <th>Cantidad</th>
    <th>Producto</th>
    <th>Unidad</th>
    <th>Cliente</th>
    <th>Añadir campo</th>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="cantidad" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="productos" />
            <option value="Selecciona el producto" >Selecciona el producto</option>
            <option value="Café en grano"> Café en grano </option>
            <option value="Café en grano 80/20"> Café en grano 80/20 </option>
            <option value="Descafeinado en grano"> Descafeinado en grano </option>
            <option value="Descafeinado sobre"> Descafeinado sobre </option>
            <option value="Azúcar"> Azúcar </option>
            <option value="Edulcorante"> Edulcorante </option>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="unidad" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="cliente" />
        </td>
        <td id="anadircampo" class="boton-anadir">Añadir campo</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
var anadir = 1;
$('#Campos').on('click', '.boton-anadir', function () {
    anadir++;
    var cantidad = "cantidad" + anadir;
    var productos = "productos" + anadir;
    var unidad = "unidad" + anadir;
    var cliente = "cliente" + anadir;
    var nuevoCampo = '<tr><td><input type="text" id=' + cantidad + ' /></td><td><select id=' + productos + ' "<option value="Selecciona el producto">Selecciona el producto</option><option value="Café en grano"> Café en grano </option><option value="Café en grano 80/20"> Café en grano 80/20 </option><option value="Descafeinado en grano"> Descafeinado en grano </option><option value="Descafeinado sobre"> Descafeinado sobre </option><option value="Azúcar"> Azúcar </option><option value="Edulcorante"> Edulcorante </option>" /></td><td><input type="text" id=' + unidad + ' /></td><td><input type="text" id=' + cliente + ' /></td><td id="anadircampo" class="boton-anadir">Añadir campo</td></tr>';
    $('#Campos').append(nuevoCampo);
});
```

I'm using CodeIgniter and jQuery 3.2.1. Source code: https://jsfiddle.net/leandroalamino/63fw9oL3/9/

Answer (score 0):

```
var nuevoCampo = '<tr><td><input type="text" id="' + cantidad + ' "/></td><td><select id="' + productos + '"><option value="Selecciona el producto">Selecciona el producto</option><option value="Café en grano"> Café en grano </option><option value="Café en grano 80/20"> Café en grano 80/20 </option><option value="Descafeinado en grano"> Descafeinado en grano </option><option value="Descafeinado sobre"> Descafeinado sobre </option><option value="Azúcar"> Azúcar </option><option value="Edulcorante"> Edulcorante </option>" /></select></td><td><input type="text" id=' + unidad + ' /></td><td><input type="text" id=' + cliente + ' /></td><td id="anadircampo" class="boton-anadir">Añadir campo</td></tr>';
```

Comment: This solution does'nt work @manoprabu-r . Adittionaly, I have tried put the script first at header.php and after at footer.php but still doesn't working.